# Problems with mysqli_rollback() using PHP and InnoDB engine

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, innodb, rollback

I have problems with rollback inside my code, I'm using PHP and the engine of all my tables are InnoDB. Below is a part of my PHP code.

```
mysqli_autocommit($conn,FALSE);
mysqli_query($conn, "START TRANSACTION");
mysqli_query($conn, $Query_insert1);
mysqli_query($conn, $Query_insert2);
mysqli_query($conn, $Query_create1);
mysqli_rollback($conn);
```

When the second insert fails, I expect it to rollback insert one but it doesn't.

Comment: What is `$Query_create1`? Are you aware that some types of SQL statements do an [implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [begin_transaction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php)() (after autocommit false) ?

And, if you use any DDL commands like create, alter or drop as part of transaction, then the transaction will get committed at that point itself.